# Fazer com que o VS Code encontre módulo instalado por comando Pip no linux

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

Instalei o matplotlib por sudo apt-get e o VS Code conseguiu encontrar a biblioteca automaticamente, entretanto com o pyserial pelo comando pip, o VS Code não consegue encontrar, como devo proceder?

Comment: Você instalou o VirtualENV (para criar diversos ambientes de desenvolvimento) ou está usando apenas uma única versão do Python no seu único ambiente principal (linux)? Qual versão do Python está utilizando? *(Certifique-se de estar conectado ao ambiente corrente em que fez a instalação da lib.)* Você testou a chamada ao módulo? *Dentro do VScode, abra o terminal e o interpretador Python. Feito isso, digite ***import serial*** para testar a existência do módulo.*

Comment: Não instalei o VirtualEnv, pois nem sabia que era necessário, mas verificarei, o Elementary OS já me instalou o Python 3 e 2, eu já testei as chamadas de import, porém só a serial que falha.

Comment: Não é necessário instalar o VirtualEnv não. Só perguntei porque isso costuma acontecer quando temos diferentes ambientes python com diferentes versões.

Verifique se você não está instalando a biblioteca referenciando a versão antiga(nativa do sistema) do Python instalada em sua máquina.

Instale utilizando o pip3: 

pip3 install pyserial

E depois, import serial no interpretador para testar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente o comando pip instalou em relação ao Python 2, então executei o

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Em seguida executei pip específico para Python 3

```
pip3 install pyserial
```

Então VS Code reconheceu automaticamente.